# Simulating a mouse click event in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am trying to simulate a mouse click event in Python on the `ui.goButton` widget.

Here is what I did:

```
QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(self.ui.goButton, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
```

Is this the right way to do it? Cause it is not working.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you mean by `simulate`? Do you want to handle mouse click event or do you want to generate a mouse click event?

Comment: @liaK: I want to generate a mouse click event, that is, I want the button to be be sent the `SIGNAL("clicked()")`, without the user actually clicking it.

Comment: Are you testing or you wan't your app to actually work that way?

Comment: @rebus: I actually want to work it that way... This maybe bad design, but I have to live with it now for the time being and get it done.

Answer (score 5):

Based on your reply to the comment, I will answer your question.

Basically signals can be *emitted* by,

```
emit signalToBeEmitted()
```

So, if you want to emit the `QPushButton`'s `clicked()` signal,

you have to inherit the `QPushButton` and you can **emit** the signal like `emit clicked()`.

[This example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#a-small-example) will help you in emitting the signals.

**But my question is why you want to do that?**

By emitting the `clicked()` signal, you will in turn call the `connect`ed slot.. So why can't you **call the slot directly** by yourself instead of emitting the signal and then calling the slot..

Remember **`slots` are just ordinary functions** which can be called just like other functions.

Or else, if the slot present in another object which you will connect through the signal, then **emit your own signal** instead of messing up with the pre-defined ones.

IMHO, **Don't emit such pre-defined signals even for the shorter term**..

Hope it helps..

Edit:

Oops I didn't see the PyQt. I am used to Qt with C++. I know nothing about Python. But I believe most of the concepts of Qt will remain common. So I will leave my answer as such..

Comment: While this is probably the right answer for the specific question from the replies, I need to simulate a true mouse click event so I can pass on a click to a widget under the mouse in a QStyledItemDelegate. I came across this question while looking in to it. I agree with the answer but I think my need is still a valid user story. It is worth adding this to this answer IMO. It may be as simple as executing mousePressEvent with a constructed event instance but I'm not sure yet....